# android loadLibrary fails when native method is used

Tags: android, android-ndk

In my test project, I use android "pay.cards" library (https://github.com/faceterteam/PayCards_Android)
I include it as AAR and it works fine.

```
compile(name:'paycards-sdk-release', ext:'aar')
```

Then I add in project native method call.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    private native String getFirstName();

    private native String getLastName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText(getFirstName());
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2)).setText(getLastName());
    }

}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
...
```

After that, pay.scan library cannot load libraries:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
    System.loadLibrary("cardrecognizer");
}
```

In this case
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in thrown.

dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/lib/arm64, /system/fake-libs64, /data/app/-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libopencv_java3.so"

But, when I disable my own native methods (just removing externalNativeBuild section from build.gradle), everything works as expected again.

Could anyone advise something in this situation?

I'm new in NDK dev, so any ideas would be helpful for me.

**UPDATE**
[image: screen]

Comment: Please check the contents of your APK. You can use **Build/Analyze APK** menu of Android Studio to see what you have under **lib** in your APK. Most likely the issue has to do with ARM 64 and 32-bit native libraries mixed incorrectly.

Comment: Alex, are all folders under lib directory are correct? Does it means that both v7a, v8a folders must contain opencv, cardrecognizer *.so files?

Comment: Looking at that PayCard SDK, it seems to generate native libraries only for armeabi-v7a. That means that any other native libraries you bundle with your app must be provided for (and only for) armeabi-v7a. That is, unless you find a way to rebuild the PayCard SDK so that it generates native libraries for additional ABIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see, the **cardrecognizer** library is built for 32-bit ARM (armeabi-v7a). In the short run, you can build you native library for the same ABI. This is usually controlled by [**abiFilters**](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#specify-abi) in the **build.gradle** script.

But if you intend to distribute your app on Play Store, you should learn to build the third-party library for arm64, too. Google [announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html) this requirement for August 2019.

Comment: Great! You really helped me! I added ndk {abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'} and it is working fine now. 
But what I don't understand is: as guys from Google says, "We are not removing 32-bit support." Does it mean, that If I leave this solution as is, it will work even after August 2018?
It work for now, so maybe there will be no changes in future as well?
And if not, is it enough to add arm64-v8a in the sdk (and create aar again) and in my build.gradle to make it workable after August 2018?

Comment: First of all, calm down. It's August 2019, you have 12 months to worry about this yet.

Comment: Not unlikely, the **cardrecognizer** library will get an update before that and acquire 64-bit support. I would recommend to get involved in GitHub, and with all due respect ask the owner to add such support. Or you can roll your sleeves up and make the necessary changes for the sake of the community.

Comment: ok)) I understand. For now, I use this fix, for 32bit arch, as you advised. It works. But for the next year, I need to think about how to save the planet! Thanks a lot!